# Stripe - Token vs Source, changing default source

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/go-serverless-manage-payments-in-your-apps-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-3528cfad770) made by a developer at Google.

In the article it says:

> Stripe offers two ways to create payment methods: Tokens and Sources. Tokens are single-use. Sources can be used more than once when attached to a customer.

What i've been doing is i've been creating creating a `Token` via `stripe.createToken(cardToSave, object : TokenCallback {...}` in my Android App, and save it into my DB. That triggers a cloud function `addPaymentSource` which creates a "payment source (card)" that gets saved to my DB:

**addPaymentSource cloud function**

```
exports.addPaymentSource = functions.database
    .ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/sources/{pushId}/token').onWrite((change, context) => {
      const source = change.after.val();
      if (source === null){
        return null;
      }
      return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.params.userId}/customer_id`)
          .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
          }).then((customer) => {
            return stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source:source});
          }).then((response) => {
            return change.after.ref.parent.set(response);
          }, (error) => {
            return change.after.ref.parent.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
          }).then(() => {
            return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
          });
        });
```

So is this a "Source" that i can reuse to make payments? I think it is because i'm able to create multiple `charges` using this "source".

**The part i'm confused is that i used a token, to create a source (or so i think it's a source). Is this correct?**

Also, whenever i add another source/card, the new card will get added to the path `"stripe_customers/$currentUser/sources/"` next to the old card. Now when i click to pay, it's still charging the old card. How do i switch cards to the new one that was added?

**EDIT**

On The Stripe website:

> If the card’s owner has no default card, then the new card will become the default. However, if the owner already has a default, then it will not change. To change the default, you should either update the customer to have a new default_source, or update the recipient to have a new

so i've tried updating the `default_source`, but it doesn't work. I honestly have no knowledge in JS, and im just winging it here... this code gives me an error

```
exports.addPaymentSource = functions.database
    .ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/sources/{pushId}/token').onWrite((change, context) => {
      const source = change.after.val();
      if (source === null){
        return null;
      }
      return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.params.userId}/customer_id`)
          .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
          }).then((customer) => {
            return stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source:source});
          }).then((customer) =>{ // look here
            return stripe.customers.update(customer.customer_id,{default_source: source}) // and here
          }).then((response) => {
            return change.after.ref.parent.set(response);
          }, (error) => {
            return change.after.ref.parent.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
          }).then(() => {
            return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers

Your code takes a Stripe token and uses it to create a Source, which is then saved on your customer. You can then reuse the Source to make payments for that customer.

For your second question, `stripe.customers.createSource` *should* automatically detach the existing Source and replace it with the one you created. If you aren't seeing this behavior, you could use `default_source` to set your new Source as the new default for your customer: https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers#attaching-a-source-to-an-existing-customer-object

Comment: can you take a look at my **edit**, i'm trying to set the new `default_source`, but i', not sure if i'm doing it correctly. I have very very little knowledge in JS